# Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" on Redhat virtual machin

Tags: linux, qt, redhat

I downloaded and installed QT5.15.12 from the official website using the command:

> $ wget https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.15/5.15.12/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.15.12.tar.xz

I used the following command to configure the project:

> $ ./configure -opensource -confirm-license -release -prefix /usr/local/Qt-5.15.12

Then, I used gmake and gmake install to compile and install Qt on my system. I am running Red Hat 9.3, and I did not encounter any issues during the compilation and installation.

To test my installation, I compiled the project located at ../examples/demos/clocks in the Qt directory. When I run the executable, I encounter the following error message:

> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use
> QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
>
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
>
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could
> be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl,
> offscreen, vnc, webgl.
>
> [2]    1245457 IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./main

I tried to set the QT_QPA_PLATFORM environment variable to "offscreen," but I received the following error message:

> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use
> QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
>
> This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()
>
> This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()